# Highchart library and responsive design

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, responsive-design

I use the library [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) and tried this example on their documentation:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/responsive

The problem is, that i have to configure more than one responsive rule to handle several max-width's. But this doesn't seem to work. The `responsive.rules` element in the chart config is an array, so i assumed i can define more than one rule like so:

```
var chartConfig = {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
[...]// Default config here for Tablet/PC
,
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 273
            },
            chartOptions: {
                [...]
                // Config for max-width 375 devices (bar chart width is 273 on my page)
            }
        },
        {
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 312
            },
            chartOptions: {
                [...]
                // Config for max-width 420 devices (bar chart width is 312 on my page)
            }
        }]
    }
```

But it won't work. The library uses only the last configuration. Anyone knows how to handle more than one responsive configuration with this library?

Comment: You should be able to change your rules order, because the rules are executed from the top down: http://jsfiddle.net/016fpuv5/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, you should be able to change your rules order, because the rules are executed from the top down: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules

> A set of rules for responsive settings. The rules are executed from
>   the top down.

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: 'condition1'
        }
      }
    }, {
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 300
      },
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: 'condition2'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

An example of your chart with changed rules order:

http://jsfiddle.net/016fpuv5/3/